# Can i improve code coverage for loop in batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, code-coverage

Firstly I wanna protect my organization code coverage,

My scenario is as follows;

I wrote 1 batch apex process, for calculate cycleTime to every products, am getting %80 covarage with this code but need more cause i will do imrovements and i dont know how can i get coverage for loop.

This Cycletime Formul Like This;

**(((OneYearBeforeStockCount + NowStockCount) / 2 ) / InvoiceCountThisProduct)*OneYear**

My Below Code,

```
global class CalculateCycleTimeBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global final string CycleTime1Year  = 'CycleTime_1_Year__c';
global final string CycleTime6Month = 'CycleTime_6_Month__c';
global final string CycleTime3Month = 'CycleTime_3_Month__c';
global final string CycleTime1Month = 'CycleTime_1_Month__c';

global final String query;
global final string field;
global final string entity;
global final string value;
global final date covarage = date.today().addDays(-365);
global List<Kesilen_Faturalar__c> InvoiceCount;
global List<Product2History> ProductHistory;
global final date startDate = date.today().addDays(-365);
global final date dayRange  = date.today();
global final decimal OneYear = 365;
global final decimal SixMonth = 182;
global final decimal ThreeMonth = 91;
global final decimal OneMonth = 30;

global final Integer StockCountFromBegin;
global Decimal CycleTime = 0; 


                global CalculateCycleTimeBatch(String q, String f, String e, string f2) {
                    query  = q;
                    field  = f;
                    entity = e;
                    value  = f2;
                }

                global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext info){
                    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
                }

                global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Product2> scope){

                    for (Product2 Product: scope) {
                    InvoiceCount = [Select Id From Kesilen_Faturalar__c Where r_n_Ad__c =: Product.Id AND CreatedDate >: startDate];   
                        if (InvoiceCount.size() > 0) {  
                            ProductHistory = [SELECT Product2Id,OldValue,NewValue,CreatedDate From Product2History WHERE Field = :value AND CreatedDate > :startDate AND Product2Id = :Product.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];                                
                             if (ProductHistory.size() > 0) {
                                 for (Product2History History : ProductHistory) {
                                     if ((Decimal)History.OldValue > 0) {
                                      Product.put(CycleTime1Year, (((Decimal)History.OldValue + (Decimal)product.Main_Stock__c) / InvoiceCount.Size()) * OneYear);
                                      Product.put(CycleTime6Month,(((Decimal)History.OldValue + (Decimal)product.Main_Stock__c) / InvoiceCount.Size()) * SixMonth);
                                      Product.put(CycleTime3Month,(((Decimal)History.OldValue + (Decimal)product.Main_Stock__c) / InvoiceCount.Size()) * ThreeMonth);
                                      Product.put(CycleTime1Month,(((Decimal)History.OldValue + (Decimal)product.Main_Stock__c) / InvoiceCount.Size()) * OneMonth);
                                         break;
                                      }
                                 }
                            }
                      }
            else {
                Product.put(Field,0);
            }
        update Product;
    }
}
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

My Test Class Below code;

```
@IsTest
public class TestCalculateCycleTime {

public static testmethod void TestCycleTimeBatchRun() {

    test.startTest(); 
    date startDate = date.today().addDays(-365);
    date dateToday = date.today();
    Integer BatchProcessLimit = 15;   
    String u      = 'Select Id,Main_Stock__c,CycleTime_1_Year__c From Product2 Where IsActive = true';
    string f      = 'CycleTime_1_Year__c';
    String e      = 'Product2';
    String f2     = 'Main_Stock__c';

    Kesilen_Faturalar__c Kss = new Kesilen_Faturalar__c();
    Kss.Name = 'BRM545854782321';
    Kss.musteri_cari_kodu__c = '0011t00000FTJiH';
    Kss.Tutar__c = 5000;
    Kss.r_n_Ad__c = '01t1t000001ZrTC';
    insert Kss;

    Product2 Prd = New Product2();
    Prd.Id = '01t1t000001ZrTC';
    Prd.Name = 'CycleTime';
    Prd.Main_Stock__c = 5;
    update Prd;

    List<Kesilen_Faturalar__c> KssList = [Select Id From Kesilen_Faturalar__c Where r_n_Ad__c = :Prd.Id];

    if (KssList.size() > 0) {  
    List<Product2History> ProductHistory = [Select OldValue,CreatedDate From Product2History Where Field = :f2 AND CreatedDate > :startDate AND Product2Id =: Prd.Id  ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC];

    if (ProductHistory.size() > 0) {
    for (Product2History History :ProductHistory) {
        if ((Decimal)History.OldValue > 0) {
        date CreatedDate = Date.newInstance(History.CreatedDate.year(), History.CreatedDate.month(), History.CreatedDate.day());
        Integer dateDifference = CreatedDate.daysBetween(dateToday);
        Prd.put('Main_Stock__c', (decimal)History.OldValue);
        Prd.put('CycleTime__c' , ((decimal)History.OldValue + Prd.Main_Stock__c) / KssList.Size() * dateDifference);
        Prd.put('InvoiceCount__c', KssList.Size());
        Prd.put('Day_Range_Stock_Count__c' , dateDifference);
                break;
        }
    }
}
    }
    else {
        Prd.put('CycleTime__c' , 0);
        Prd.put('InvoiceCount__c', 0);
        Prd.put('Day_Range_Stock_Count__c' , 0);
    }
    Update Prd;

    ID jobid = Database.executeBatch(new CalculateCycleTimeBatch(u,f,e,f2),BatchProcessLimit);
    test.stopTest();
}
}
```

And My Code Coverage Color,

[image: In my class covarage mistakes]

Answer (score 0):

Line number 48 in the screenshot:

```
if (ProductHistory.size() > 0)
```

This condition for you is returning false, hence not executing the for loop within the if, what I would suggest is you create test data for Product2History in your test class.

```
Product2History objProduct2History = new Product2History(OldValue = 'oldVal');
insert objProduct2History;
```